# Какие команды нужны чтобы парсер дискорда брал сообщения из конкретного сервери и канала на нем?

Tags: python, telebot, discord, бот

Я новичок и поэтому мои ошибки могут быть глупые и детские. У меня возникла проблема при написание парсера в discord , при запуске он начинает парсить все сообщения со всех серверов и каналов, мне же нужно чтобы он брал именно с тех каналов и серверов которые я указал. Я использовал библиотеку discum и не нашел там как это реализовать , только пример который парсит все. Какие есть варианты решения этой проблемы?

```
import discum
import discord

bot = discum.Client(token="токен аккаунта", log=False)


@bot.gateway.command
def helloworld(resp):
    if resp.event.ready_supplemental:  # ready_supplemental is sent after ready
        user = bot.gateway.session.user
        print("Logged in as {}#{}".format(user['username'], user['discriminator']))
    if resp.event.message:
        m = resp.parsed.auto()
        guildID = m['guild_id'] if 'guild_id' in m else None  # because DMs are technically channels too
        channelID = m['channel_id']
        username = m['author']['username']
        discriminator = m['author']['discriminator']
        content = m['content']
        print("> guild {} channel {} | {}#{}: {}".format(guildID, channelID, username, discriminator, content))


bot.gateway.run(auto_reconnect=True)
```

Comment: Ну, проверяйте с какого сервера и/или канала пришло сообщение.

Comment: Зачем? Если у меня бот показывает с какого севера и канала он спарсил , мне же нужно чтобы он парсил с конкретного сервера и канала , которые я ему указал